# Source code for nltk.chat.util not running? - Beginner

Tags: python, nltk

When I try to run this code in Sublime, it just print [Finished in 0.2s].
What am I doing wrong? Isn't it suppose to be running a chatbot in the console? I found this code [here](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/chat/util.html)

I know this is a basic question but I am new to python and nltk.

```
# Natural Language Toolkit: Chatbot Utilities
#
# Copyright (C) 2001-2016 NLTK Project
# Authors: Steven Bird <stevenbird1@gmail.com>
# URL: <http://nltk.org/>
# For license information, see LICENSE.TXT

# Based on an Eliza implementation by Joe Strout <joe@strout.net>,
# Jeff Epler <jepler@inetnebr.com> and Jez Higgins <jez@jezuk.co.uk>.
from __future__ import print_function

import re
import random
from nltk import compat

reflections = {
"i am"       : "you are",
"i was"      : "you were",
"i"          : "you",
"i'm"        : "you are",
"i'd"        : "you would",
"i've"       : "you have",
"i'll"       : "you will",
"my"         : "your",
"you are"    : "I am",
"you were"   : "I was",
"you've"     : "I have",
"you'll"     : "I will",
"your"       : "my",
"yours"      : "mine",
"you"        : "me",
"me"         : "you"
}


class Chat(object):
    def __init__(self, pairs, reflections={}):
        """
        Initialize the chatbot.  Pairs is a list of patterns and    responses.  Each
    pattern is a regular expression matching the user's statement or question,
    e.g. r'I like (.*)'.  For each such pattern a list of possible responses
    is given, e.g. ['Why do you like %1', 'Did you ever dislike %1'].  Material
    which is matched by parenthesized sections of the patterns (e.g. .*) is mapped to
    the numbered positions in the responses, e.g. %1.

    :type pairs: list of tuple
    :param pairs: The patterns and responses
    :type reflections: dict
    :param reflections: A mapping between first and second person expressions
    :rtype: None
    """

    self._pairs = [(re.compile(x, re.IGNORECASE),y) for (x,y) in pairs]
    self._reflections = reflections
    self._regex = self._compile_reflections()


def _compile_reflections(self):
    sorted_refl = sorted(self._reflections.keys(), key=len,
            reverse=True)
    return  re.compile(r"\b({0})\b".format("|".join(map(re.escape,
        sorted_refl))), re.IGNORECASE)

def _substitute(self, str):
    """
    Substitute words in the string, according to the specified reflections,
    e.g. "I'm" -> "you are"

    :type str: str
    :param str: The string to be mapped
    :rtype: str
    """

    return self._regex.sub(lambda mo:
            self._reflections[mo.string[mo.start():mo.end()]],
                str.lower())

def _wildcards(self, response, match):
    pos = response.find('%')
    while pos >= 0:
        num = int(response[pos+1:pos+2])
        response = response[:pos] + \
            self._substitute(match.group(num)) + \
            response[pos+2:]
        pos = response.find('%')
    return response

def respond(self, str):
    """
    Generate a response to the user input.

    :type str: str
    :param str: The string to be mapped
    :rtype: str
    """

    # check each pattern
    for (pattern, response) in self._pairs:
        match = pattern.match(str)

        # did the pattern match?
        if match:
            resp = random.choice(response)    # pick a random response
            resp = self._wildcards(resp, match) # process wildcards

            # fix munged punctuation at the end
            if resp[-2:] == '?.': resp = resp[:-2] + '.'
            if resp[-2:] == '??': resp = resp[:-2] + '?'
            return resp

# Hold a conversation with a chatbot


def converse(self, quit="quit"):
    input = ""
    while input != quit:
        input = quit
        try: input = compat.raw_input(">")
        except EOFError:
            print(input)
        if input:
            while input[-1] in "!.": input = input[:-1]
            print(self.respond(input))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file you show contains utility software used by the chatbot programs.  You do not directly run that file as a python script.

Go to [this nltk.org page](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.chat.html) and download a chatbot program such as nltk.chat.eliza, and run it with python.

I assume that you have installed the required nltk software for your system.
I tested the eliza chatbot in a Linux terminal emulator and it worked as expected.  Sorry, I don't know Sublime and cannot help you with that tool.